# How to convert a value to currency format with 2 decimals?

Tags: jquery, currency

How can I convert the last 2 numbers of a given value as the decimals of a currency value?

Sample: 2499 should come out as 24,99 and not 2,499.00 what I am currently getting.

```js
var price = $('.album').data("totalprice");
    
var newPrice = price.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');

console.log(newPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="2499"></div>
```

Comment: Assuming you're using `,` as the decimal separator, divide the original value by `100`

Comment: for whatever reason we have two downvotes here..... If I would know the answer or if I had found an existing solution here I would not have asked for help

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I would presume it's because this is an extremely simple maths issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) after dividing the amount by 100

```js
const n = 2499;
const f = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
}).format(n / 100);
console.log(f);
```

See the different parameters available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Parameter). Of course you can also use Schweizer Franken as your currency

Comment: Both given answers are working and super. I take the other one as the accepted answer as that solution is closer to my previous code. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Use this `\d{2}` and remove  trailing .00 using split

```js
var price = $('.album').data("totalprice");
    
var newPrice = price.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{2})+\.)/g, '$&,');

console.log(newPrice.split('.')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album" data-totalprice="2499"></div>
```

Comment: Both given answers are working and super. I take this one as the accepted answer as the solution is closer to my previous code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm, not yet finished. If the original price ist 2 digits + 2 decimals it does work perfectly. If the price is 3 digits long + 2 decimals, something weird comes out as a result. eg.  16749 should be 167,49, but result ist 1,67,49